# How to tell if Koji rice is bad?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, fermentation

I have some store bought Cold Mountain brand Koji rice. On the container it says it keeps in the fridge for "6-12 months". I've had it for about 8 months, but can detect no change from when I bought it by either sight (still white and chalky), touch (perfectly dry), or smell (not sour, a little sweet).

That said, this is a fungus we're dealing with, so I want to be sure I can still use it.

How can I tell if Koji rice is still good to use?

Comment: Did you have a look at [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question.  it's your kitchen, your body, your health, and your confidence.  if you've lost confidence in an ingredient, toss it and buy new.

Comment: @jim - food safety isn't determined by my confidence and my senses are fallible. I'm not too familiar with koji, so I'm looking for a halfway objective test to decide whether I _should be_ confident in using it.

Comment: @Halhex - I just did and neither of the linked sites (StillTasty and Food Keeper) or the answer itself answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check for any signs of mold growth or discoloration. If the Koji rice appears moldy, discolored (other than its typical white color), or has visible patches of green, blue, or black, it is best to discard it.
2. Koji rice should be dry and have a powdery or chalky texture. If you notice any clumping, stickiness, or a significant change in texture, it may indicate moisture absorption or spoilage.
3. Koji rice typically has a pleasant, sweet, and slightly fermented aroma. If you detect any unpleasant or off-putting odors such as a strong sour smell or a moldy/musty scent, it is best to avoid using it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Back when I asked this question, I indeed did not observe any of these red flags.